# Partitioning a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: python

I know partition() exists, but it only takes in one value, I'm trying to partition around various values:

for example say I wanted to partition around symbols in a string:

input: "function():"

output: ["function", "(", ")", ":"]

I can't seem to find an efficient way to handle variable amounts of partitioning.

Comment: This seems like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: At any rate, if you don't want this question removed, you should make sure you read [ask] and provide your [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern that matches either a word or a non-space character:

```
re.findall(r'\w+|\S', s)
```

so that given `s = 'function():'`, this returns:

```
['function', '(', ')', ':']
```

Comment: OP asked for "partitioning" the string, and I immediately thought "split", but _finding_ the tokens indeed makes more sense, intuitively...

Answer (score 1):

You could `re.split` by `\W` and use `(...)` to keep the delimiters, then remove empty parts.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "function(): return foo + 3"
>>> [s for s in re.split(r"(\W)", s) if s.strip()]
['function', '(', ')', ':', 'return', 'foo', '+', '3']
```

Note that this will split after *every* special character; if you want to keep certain groups of special characters together, e.g. `==` or `<=`, you should test those first with `|`.

```
>>> s = "function(): return foo + 3 == 42"
>>> [s for s in re.split(r"(\W)", s) if s.strip()]
['function', '(', ')', ':', 'return', 'foo', '+', '3', '=', '=', '42']
>>> [s for s in re.split(r"(==|!=|<=|\W)", s) if s.strip()]
['function', '(', ')', ':', 'return', 'foo', '+', '3', '==', '42']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using only `list`: (kinda ugly, though :))

```py
import typing as t


def partition(s: str, seps: t.Iterable[str]):
    if not s or not seps:
        return [s]
    st1, st2 = [s], []
    for sep in set(seps):
        while st1:
            st2.append(st1.pop())
            while True:
                x1, x2, x3 = st2.pop().rpartition(sep)
                if not x2:  # `sep` not found
                    st2.append(x3)
                    break
                if not x1:
                    st2.extend([x3, x2] if x3 else [x2])
                    break
                st2.extend([x3, x2, x1] if x3 else [x2, x1])
        while st2:
            st1.append(st2.pop())
    return st1


assert partition('abcdbcd', ['a']) == ['a', 'bcdbcd']
assert partition('abcdbcd', ['b']) == ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'b', 'cd']
assert partition('abcdbcd', ['d']) == ['abc', 'd', 'bc', 'd']
assert partition('abcdbcd', ['e']) == ['abcdbcd']
assert partition('abcdbcd', ['b', 'd']) == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd']
assert partition('abcdbcd', ['db']) == ['abc', 'db', 'cd']
```